# Scala future with unknown loop count

Tags: scala, future

The case is try to get children comment list for a comment, and it is easy to get all the children comments by a 'parentId' field in database. However, take the possible long list into consideration, it's better to do pagination for db query. We can get specified rows like this:

```scala
  def getChildCommentsByParentId(parentId: Int, offset: Int, rows: Int): Future[Seq[CommentsRow]] = {
    val query = Comments.filter(row => row.iparentid === parentId && row.istatus === statusNormal ).drop(offset).take(rows)
    db.run(query.result)
  }
```

For getting all the rows by doing several pagination call with a fixed page size, it's easy to express this in an iterative way in other programing language, like this:

```
           $replyList = [];
           do {
               $ret = getChildCommentsByParentId(parentId, page * pagesize, pagesize);
               if (!empty($ret)) {
                   $replyList = array_merge($replyList, $ret);
               }
               if (count($ret) < $pageSize) {
                   break;
               }
               $page ++ ;
           } while(true);
```

It's reasonable to use for comprehension to handle multiple futures in scala, but i don't know how to handle this case. The key point is, current iteration depends on previous one(the 'page' parameter), and when the count of rows is less than pagesize, returns a full result with all the previous data rows.

Thanks!

Comment: Is that php? what would the execution behavior be in that piece of code? I assume it is sequential. You first have to decide if you want the multiple calls to the DB execute sequentially or concurrently. The former being not so performant, the latter being a little bit trickier

Comment: yeah, it's php...I'm doing refractory work for replacing php with scala, but for now i found scala's future much less friendly than php's coroutine when you have to call db in a nested way.

Comment: The execution behavior is sequential. It should depend the previous db pagination call to decide whether call for next page data. @sinanspd

Comment: it may come across unfriendly if you aren't used to compositional programming. Anyhow, why not just define a recursive function? Once the future in the body resolved it will do a callback to the same function, until you need to stop

Comment: I have tried to solve it in a recursive way, please review it in the answer. I just wrote it and not have it tested yet, may have bugs. @sinanspd

Comment: _"returns a full result with all the previous data rows"_ why do you want to do pagination if you want to combine all the results into a big sequence?

Comment: emm……that's a good question. It's old logic i'm trying refactoring. Cause children comment maybe a huge number and unpredictable, so doing pagination can divide high performance overhead into each call whose row count is limited. Moreover, it can avoid index don't take effect due to large result set.  In short, it isn't a pagination for frontend but for database. @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez

Answer (score 0):

I try to solve it in a recursive way:

```scala
  def getChildComments(nextPage: Int, commentId: Int) : Future[CommentResult] = {

    val pageSize = 5

    val currentPageFuture = commentModel.getChildCommentsByParentId(commentId, nextPage*pageSize, pageSize).map {
      data => CommentResult(nextPage, data)
    }

    val nextPageFuture = currentPageFuture.flatMap({ commentRes =>
      val nextPage = commentRes.nextPage+1
      if(commentRes.data.size >= pageSize) {
        getChildComments(nextPage, commentId)
      }
      else {
        Future.successful(CommentResult(nextPage, Seq()))
      }
    })

    for {
      currentPageComments <- currentPageFuture
      nextPageComments <- nextPageFuture
    } yield {
      CommentResult(currentPageComments.nextPage, currentPageComments.data ++ nextPageComments.data)
    }
  }

  case class CommentResult(nextPage: Int, data: Seq[TbcommentsRow])
```

But still feel it's ugly, doubt it has more elegant way?

Comment: What about something like [this](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/d8zSwmunRU6HLMMOnunlgg)? You can replace the `Option` with your size logic.

Comment: For reference  @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez 's is more like what I meant.

Comment: Thanks bro. It's much cleaner and conciser. But if want to combine all the results into a big sequence,  it still need more effort. @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez

Comment: @BugSource I really don't understand what is the point... but whatever, you would do it like this: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/d8zSwmunRU6HLMMOnunlgg/3

Comment: Amazing!! Learned a lot. @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez